# Monero Wallet RPC seemingly stuck on sync?

Tags: monero-wallet-rpc

I'm currently experimenting with the wallet RPC. I'm using version 0.18.1.0 on stagenet with a remote daemon (tried multiple ones).

When I open (or restore) a wallet, the (what I assume) syncing or scanning gets stuck.
The log level is at 4 and I see about 400-430 "process_new_transaction" entries and then it gets stuck.

The RPC server doesn't respond to HTTP requests anymore and also not to SIGTERM.

These are the parameters I use:

```
--daemon-address http://node.monerodevs.org:38089 --stagenet --rpc-restricted-bind-ip 127.0.0.1 --rpc-bind-port <random_port> --rpc-login <random_user>:<random_pw> --disable-rpc-ban --wallet-dir wallets --log-file rpc.log --log-level 4 --non-interactive --max-concurrency 4
```

Here's the log: https://hastebin.com/poyopixage.yaml

Hopefully someone can help, I did some research but did not find any solution unfortunately.
Thanks for your attention.

Comment: The remote node you are trying to connect to, is it your own or simply a node you found online?

Comment: its a public one found on monero.fail, however i tried multiple ones

Comment: The node may not be up to date. Could you use RINO's node? It is listed on `community.rino.io`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, apparently the rpc server stops working when stdout/-err is not read for some time. I dont know if some kind of internal buffer fills up or something.

Reading stdout (and in my case, just discarding it) fixes everything, the rpc server works fine again.